# gettin a pasword hashed with node ks bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

Wha I shoul do for get the password hashed and use it for insert in my DB

```
const company = req.params.company;
const name = req.params.name;
const password = req.params.password;

bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
});
```

If I use the const password it passes without be hashed

Answer (score 0):

Using the hash params, that returns a hashed value for the callback.

```
bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
     const object = {
        company, name, password: hash;
     }
     await db.save(object);

});
```